# In Javascript, how to avoid the "escaping" in createTextElement method?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, fonts

Here is the Jsfiddle [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8a5e7La3/)

```js
document.getElementById("container").appendChild(document.createTextNode('&#xe145; '))
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="container" class="material-icons"></div>
<br>
<div class="material-icons">&#xe145;</div>
```

I have two `<div>` node.

`&#xe145;` is the actual character code for "plus sign" in the font.

However, the one which is appended `&#xe145;` by Javascript  doesn't work.

It seems that `&#xe145;` is escaped by `createTextNode` or `appendChild`...

Does anyone have ideas about how to avoid the escaping..

Comment: That's because you are creating a textNode. Create an element and use the `innerHTML` property. http://jsfiddle.net/8a5e7La3/1/

Comment: @Vohuman Thanks! But using `innerHTML` may be quite unsafe.. Is there a way to allow safe characters (no HTML structure) without escaping for `&#xe145;`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you create a text node, you're skipping the HTML parse step that would recognize entity notation and produce the corresponding content.

You can use a JavaScript escape sequence however:

```
document.getElementById("container").appendChild(document.createTextNode('\ue145'))
```

The string in the JavaScript code *is* parsed, but it's parsed according to the rules of JavaScript syntax, not HTML syntax.

Answer (score 2):

`&#xe145;` is an `html` entity in hex

Try utilizing `.innerHTML`

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("container");
elem.innerHTML = "&#xe145;";
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="container" class="material-icons"></div>
<br>
<div class="material-icons">&#xe145;</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!  Is there any documentation about the notation of `&#xe145;` and `'\ue145'`..

Comment: @hanfeisun See http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e145/index.htm . Note, "+" could be rendered at displayed html utilizing `css` psuedo element as well. –

Answer (score 0):

> using `innerHTML` may be quite unsafe

You can write a *RegExp* with `str.replace` to decode *html entities* in *Strings* if you want to avoid *innerHTML*

```
function decode_html_entities(str) {
    return str.replace(/&(?:#x((?:[0-9a-f]{2}){1,2})|#(\d{1,3})|(amp));/ig, function () {
        if (arguments[1] || arguments[2])
            return String.fromCharCode(arguments[1] ? parseInt(arguments[1], 16) : parseInt(arguments[2], 10));
        var i,
            map = ['&']; // this matches &amp;, add more to the regexp for others
        for (i = 3; i < arguments.length; ++i)
            if (arguments[i]) return map[i-3];
    });
}
```